# How to update json document from previous collection to latest collection if document exists .in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, data-ingestion

I have datahub flow that ingest data into marklogic database.
I need to update json document from previous collection to latest collection if document exist

previously I was doing full load deleting the documents and reinserting it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xdmp.documentSetCollections()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.documentSetCollections) to change all the collections on a document.

Your requirements are a little vague, but since you mention "if the document exists", you would most likely need to use a custom step in DHF or a step interceptor to apply whatever logic you need before adjusting the collections.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the volume of documents to which you want to rename collection. If you want to rename (collection of) all the documents that are in old-collection, here is the XQuery code

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $OLD-COLLECTION := "old"
let $NEW-COLLECTION := "new"
for $uri in xdmp:node-uri(fn:collection($OLD-COLLECTION))
return
  (
    xdmp:document-add-collections($uri,$NEW-COLLECTION),
    xdmp:document-remove-collections($uri,$OLD-COLLECTION)
  )
```

Our answers can only be as good as the question itself. Please try to elaborate your question a bit more